# How can I do a presence check in Java? i am getting an error.

Tags: java

i am trying to do a presence check in java on 10 JTextFields. I want it so that if all 10 of my textfield have something in them, it will do my code.

```
String input1 = tfQ1.getText();
String input2 = tfQ2.getText();
```

etc.

I have put

```
IF(input1==("")&&input2==("")&&input3==("")&&input4==("")&&input5==("")&&input6==("")&&input7==("")&&input8==("")&&input9==("")&&input10==(""))
{
//DO SCORES ETC
}
```

However, this doesnt do anything... (my button does not work weather there are things in the text fields or not)
Please and someone help with presence check validation? Thanks =)

Comment: In Java you use `.equals` to compare strings, not `==`.

Comment: If your condition would work, it would check if all of them are empty.

Comment: How can i make it so that i checks for anything? nothing specific? thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of "==" operator you should use

```
input1.equals("")
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves one problem but i have just realised, i dont know what i was it to equal to? The text fields are for a user to input a spelling for a spelling test and i want to check they have written an answer for every question? Do you know how to make it so it checks for any input, not a specific word =) Thanks, sorry im being a pain, im new to this

Answer (score 0):

```
if(input.equals("WhateverYouAreLookingFor")) {
    //do this
}else {
    //do this
}
```

`==` is a reference comparison, both objects point to the same location in memory. essentially it tests wether the two operands refer to the same object.

`.equals()` will only compare what is in the String. It can be overridden so two distinct objects can still be equal.

Comment: Thanks, this solves one problem but i have just realised, i dont know what i was it to equal to? The text fields are for a user to input a spelling for a spelling test and i want to check they have written an answer for every question? Do you know how to make it so it checks for any input, not a specific word =) Thanks, sorry im being a pain, im new to this